# phonegap node.js - build fails because of node_modules

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cordova

I recently wrote a very basic node.js application and would like to build the client side in phonegap. However, I think the build fails with the node_modules in the src directory. I have a remote mongodb set up and not sure how to access that without my server.js file (which requires the node_modules folder to run). I'm sure there must be a way past this but can't find anything so far.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not yet a like a cdn of mongodb you can use through the client side.
You can solve it using in the server side the mongodb and socket.io npm dependencies and trough web sockets sending the data to the client side.